# ssh -T github.com -> Wrong username in response message

Tags: git, ssh

My git username is 'new_username' now, and I can git pull usually.

But sometimes, Suddenly can't git pull cause I don't know.

```
$ git pull
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And it strange run follow command for resolution.

```
$ ssh -T github.com
Hi old_username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not             provide shell access.
```

'old_username' is my old git username I'v used in past.

Why?

vim ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
  name = new_username
  email = new_username@xxx.com
```

And for now, reboot My Mac OS then I can git pull.

Comment: GitHub username is not the same thing as the name you set in Git.

Answer (score 2):

Github username is recognized by the public ssh key you imported to your account. If you use the same for more accounts, there might be some problems.

Comment: So the solution is to remove the SSH key from Github and create a new one and upload that one then?

Comment: @Mr.Web If you do not have access to the old account to remove the key from there, just create a new key and add it to your account. Otherwise removing it from the old account (and making sure it is added to the new one) should be enough.